# Convergence of normal derivative in Sobolev space $H^1$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, fractional-sobolev-spaces, trace-map

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain, $u_k\in H^1(\Omega)$, $k=1,2,..$ and the normal derivative $\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial \mathbf{n}}\in L^2(\partial\Omega)$. As $k$ goes to infinity, $u_k$ converges weakly in $H^1(\Omega)$ to $u\in H^1(\Omega)$, and the normal derivative $\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial \mathbf{n}}$ converges weakly in $L^2(\partial\Omega)$ to $g\in L^2(\partial\Omega)$.

Given all the above, can we conclude that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}}=g$?

If needed, we can also assume that $u_k$ satisfies $\int_{\Omega} \nabla u_k\cdot \nabla \varphi-u_k\varphi = \int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial \mathbf{n}}\varphi$, $\forall \varphi\in H^1(\Omega)$.

A candidate proof using the addition assumption of variational equation was as follows. Passing to the limit of the variational form, we get
$$(1)\quad\int_{\Omega} \nabla u\cdot \nabla \varphi-u\varphi = \int_{\partial\Omega} g\varphi,\quad \forall \varphi\in H^1(\Omega).$$ If the following equality holds:
$$
(2)\quad
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u\cdot \nabla \varphi = 
\int_{\Omega} (-\Delta u) \varphi + \int_{\partial\Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}}\varphi,\quad \forall \varphi\in H^1(\Omega),
$$
then (1) can be substituted to
$$
(3)\quad
\int_{\Omega} (-\Delta u - u) \varphi = \int_{\partial\Omega} (g-\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}})\varphi,\quad \forall \varphi\in H^1(\Omega).
$$
Taking $\varphi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in (3), we get $-\Delta u - u=0$ and hence $g=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}}$.

However, I am not sure about (2). In what sense is $-\Delta u$ defined in (2)? If $-\Delta u$ is defined in $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)=(C_c^{\infty}(\Omega))'$, then $-\Delta u$ may not be applicable to $\varphi\in H^1(\Omega)$ and formal integration by part $\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla \phi=\int_{\Omega}(-\Delta u)\phi$ can not generate a boundary term for $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

(2) can be justified in this way(?). Taking $\varphi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in (1), we get $-\Delta u - u=0$ in $D'(\Omega)$. Since $u\in H^1(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)$, we get $\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega)$. In this case, (2) is justified.

Comment: For a general $u \in H^1$, you cannot define a normal derivative $\partial u / \partial n \in L^2(\partial\Omega)$.

Comment: @gerw You are right. But in the question, the existence of $\partial u_k/\partial \mathbf{n}$ is a given condition and $u$ is the weak limit of $u_n$ in $H^1$. Did you mean even with the given conditions that $\partial u/\partial\mathbf{n}$ may not exist?

Comment: Every $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ can be approximated by $\varphi_k \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Note that $\partial \varphi_k / \partial n = 0$. If your question could be answered affirmatively, you would have $\partial u / \partial n = 0$ for all $u \in H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Btw: How do you define "existence of $\partial u_k / \partial n$"?

Comment: @gerw Your statement about approximation of $H^1$ by $C_c^{\infty}$ must be wrong because the closure of $C_c^{\infty}$ in $H^1$ is $H^1_0$ -- a proper subspace of $H^1$.

Comment: @gerw For example, consider the hat function $1-r$ on the unit disk with $r$ the distance to the center. This function is in $H^1$ and has well-defined normal derivative on the boundary of the disk.

Comment: Yes, I meant $H_0^1$. Your function $1-r$ belongs to $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and my argument would show that the normal derivative is zero.